# HTML Checkboxes with Javascript Functions

Tags: javascript, html

I'm just trying to get this checkbox to alert a message after it is checked and after it is unchecked by running a function in Javascript.  I can get it to display the "checked" message but can't get the "unchecked" alert to come up.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chbx" onchange="foo()">
<script type="text/javascript">
var checkbox = document.getElementById("chbx");

 function foo(){
   if(checkbox.checked=true){
       alert("Checked!");
         }
   else {
        alert("UnChecked!");
         }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: You need to use `==` or `===`, as what you're doing is *setting* the value (true every time). The second form is best. (Nevermind, I see you edited out the incorrect syntax.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've got single-equals instead of double-equals in your if statements:

```
if (checkbox.checked=true) {
```

should be

```
if (checkbox.checked == true) {
```

or just

```
if (checkbox.checked) {
```

Answer (score 4):

You are not comparing values using `=`. Needs to be at least `==`, better `===`

```
if(checkbox.checked === true) {}
```

or, simplified

```
if(checkbox.checked) {}
```

Comment: @DanBarzilay: excuse me ? Why not, `===` just compares *type* AND *value* so its much more precise. Even if it makes no difference here, I just mentioned its "better".

Comment: `===` is for type and a boolean is a boolean it doesn't matter if its true or false.. it should be `==`

Comment: @DanBarzilay: I don't agree with you. Just for convinience `===` should always be used in this language to avoid crucial errors/confusion with types

Comment: @DanBarzilay - It can be. Crockford, for one, says always use `===`. So it's not "wrong" or "bad" in this case, it just happens that both are equivalent and work in this situation.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Sorry, my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

You made the commonly made mistake of using a single `=` this actual sets the `checkbox.checked` to true. If you want to make a comparison make sure to use a double `==`.

Also, there are only two options for a checkbox; so if it's not on it's off:

This is what I would have done:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chbx" onchange="checkbox_changed()">
<script type="text/javascript">
    var checkbox = document.getElementById("chbx");

    function checkbox_changed() {
        if (checkbox.checked == true) {
            alert("Checked!");
        } else {
            alert("UnChecked!");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You're making the same mistake the OP did with the condition (a single `=`).